# Integrating Felix into Netbeans 8.0

Tags: java, owl, apache-felix, protege, netbeans-8

I want to develop a protegé plugin using Netbeans. So, someone suggest for me using Netbeans OSGIs dor that. I haven't yet known how it helps in my work. However, I chose Felix and I am following this [link](http://felix.apache.org/site/integrating-felix-with-netbeans.html). Unfortunately, I followed it step by step and am blocked at this step
[image]
However, for me, it doesn't workfor me. Instead, it displays me:
[image]

Thank you for helping me and advise me if I am at the wrong way.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Felix, but a quick glance at its webpage doesn't indicate to me how this is related to the Web Ontology Language (OWL, tag: [tag:owl]), or Protege (an OWL ontology editor, tag: [tag:protege]).  Is it related somehow?  I don't understand why these tags are here.

Comment: JUST because I am trying to implement a Protegé plugin. This implementation uses Netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

1) Check out this project from GitHub
( https://github.com/protegeproject/protege-plugin-examples )

git clone https://github.com/protegeproject/protege-plugin-examples.git

2) Open it (the folder) as **an existing project** with NetBeans 8

3) Build it.

---

If you want get deeper into developing production-ready applications using OSGi,
I'd like to suggest to take a look on the Apache Sling Launchpad project.

( http://www.eclipsecon.org/2013/sites/eclipsecon.org.2013/files/2013_EclipseConSlingInstaller.pdf )

( https://github.com/apache/sling )

The Sling Launchpad does not depend on other Sling specific bundles and can be used even without the Apache Sling framework.

It makes everyday life much more comfortable.

You just add the following snippet to your plugin's pom.xml and every time you build the plugin project NetBeans updates the plugin in the felix container.

```
...
      <build>
        <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-sling-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>install-bundle</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>install</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>

            </plugins>
        </build>
```

...